# HTTPS in PAC file

Tags: proxy, pac

I am writing a .pac file for use with iOS5 without jailbreak, but I feel trouble in matching the url starting with "https" (eg: https://test.com).

Here is my script:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
  if (shExpMatch(url, "https://*")) return "PROXY 123.123.123.123";
  return 'DIRECT';
}
```

And if I matched "https://test.com", how can I return "https://123.123.123.123" to the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

`if (shExpMatch(url, "https:**"))`

This should fix it.